# Functionality like Polynode

Tags: spring-boot, svg, d3.js, vuejs3

I want to implement something that looks like Polynode.

I'm building charts using d3.js and vue.js 3 and want to do the following:

After generating the chart I want to save the SVG representation of generated chart into the db like mongoDb and then after reloading the page load the generated svg into the view, but I want to be able to interact with the chart meaning move nodes and manipulate the data on the loaded svg file to basically continue the editing of the chart to my liking.

P.S. I didn't implemented it yet, I'm in the process of researching how to do it... if my thought process described above is incorrect please guide me to the correct way to think about the problem, and if the thought process is good please help me by telling me how to actually achieve it.

Thank you in advance...

For the backend I'm using spring boot.

As I mentioned above, I'm in the process of research and currently am little bit lost...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you ? :
https://observablehq.com/@fil/save-a-force-directed-graph-to-localstorage
as they say : "This Force-Directed Graph saves its nodes with fixed positions to localStorage, so you can restart where you left. Move a few points around, then reload the page."

You could do the same by storing in db instead of local storage
And instead of storing fixed node, you could store all node positions.